# Split and matching a space in regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, split

I need to split a string by whitespace with matching a space character in a PHP regular expression. How can I do that?

```
$string = "microsoft office home and business 38.1 24 N/A 76.3"
```

And split it to:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => microsoft office home and business
>       [1] => 38.1
>       [2] => 24
>       [3] => N/A
>       [4] => 76.3
>   )

I tried this, but it did not work for me:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z $]/", "", $string);
```

Comment: What about the whitespace in "This is a word"?  Why aren't you splitting those? Besides, why not use `explode()`?

Comment: `explode(' ',$string)`

Comment: sorry for my mistake, "This is a word" should be "this is a name"... eg. "microsoft office home and business"
so I cannot split it by space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
$string = "This is a name 38 24 N/A 76";
$regex  = '/([^0-9]+) ([\dN\.\/A ]+)/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $m);

$name  = $m[1];
$parts = explode(' ', $m[2]);

var_dump($name, $parts);

// You get:
// string(14) "This is a name"
// array(4) {
  // [0]=>
  // string(2) "38"
  // [1]=>
  // string(2) "24"
  // [2]=>
  // string(3) "N/A"
  // [3]=>
  // string(2) "76"
// }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it work for integer, but if the string is "This is a name 38.0 24.1 N/A 76", the output will be 
string(14) "This is a name" array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "38" }
Sorry for my poor regex knowledge lol

Comment: I didn't see the float. I edited the regexp so floats are matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can split based on this

```
\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5bD0/3

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all()` with the following expression:

```
^(?P<name>\D+)
([\d.]+)\h*
([\d.]+)\h*
([NA/]+)\h*
([\d.]+)$
```

See it working on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uU7aS6/1) (mind the modifiers!).

---

In `PHP` this comes down to:

```
<?php

$regex = '~
        ^(?P<name>\D+)
        ([\d.]+)\h*
        ([\d.]+)\h*
        ([NA/]+)\h*
        ([\d.]+)$~xm';

$string = 'microsoft office home and business 38.1 24 N/A 76.3
This is a name 38.0 24.1 N/A 76';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See a [**working demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/8n729V) as well.